# Find an equation of the tangent to the curve at the given point

Tags: calculus

Find an equation of the tangent to the curve at the given point
$$x = cos(t) + cos(2t)$$    $$y = sin(t) + sin(2t)$$    $$Point :(−1, 1)$$

$$...$$

$$y = sin(t) + 2sin(t)cos(t)$$
$$-2sin(t)cos(t) = sin(t)$$
$$cos(t)=-1/2$$
$$t=2\pi/3$$

$$x = cos(2\pi/3) + cos(4\pi/3) = -1$$
$$y = sin(2\pi/3) + cos(4\pi/3) = 0$$

point should be (-1,1), but it is (-1,0), how do I find t for this point?

Comment: check the plot http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametricplot+%28cos%28t%29%2Bcos%282t%29%2Csin%28t%29%2Bsin%282t%29%29

Comment: Think first what you need to do in the most simple case. Then try to figure out how it should go in this case. For instance, if the problem asked you to find the tangent for a function $x(t)$ at a point $x=x_*$, what would you need to do? Now instead of just one function $x(t)$ you have two: $x(t)$ and  $y(t)$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you solved the equation $y=0$ for $t.$ Rather, you *could* try to solve $y=1$. That is: $$1=\sin t+\sin(2t)$$

Unfortunately, that's a bear to solve, so instead, I would recommend solving $x=-1,$ first. Then $$-1=\cos t+\cos(2t)=\cos t+2\cos^2t-1$$ by double-angle formula. We can rewrite this as $$0=(1+2\cos t)\cos t.$$ Thus, either $\cos t=0$ or $\cos t=-\frac12.$ This gives possible solutions:

$$t=\frac\pi2+2\pi n,\frac{3\pi}2+2\pi n,\frac{2\pi}3+2\pi n,\frac{4\pi}3+2\pi n$$

Which of these satisfy $y=1$? Can you figure that out and take it from there?

Comment: how did you get all the other values, when inverse cos(-1/2) = 2\pi/3 ? is there a trick with the calculator I can do or do I have to memorize unit circle?

Comment: also how did u get cos(t) = 0?

Comment: The term "inverse cosine" is a misnomer, since the cosine function is not one-to-one, so has no inverse. The *arccosine* of a number $t$ is the angle $\theta$ in the interval $[0,\pi]$ such that $\cos\theta=t.$ Of course, putting $\theta_0=\arccos t,$ we have $\cos(\theta_0+2\pi n)=t$ for any $n\in\Bbb Z,$ and that $\cos(2\pi-\theta_0+2\pi n)$ for any $n\in\Bbb Z.$ If we keep the unit circle in mind, each of these claims should be fairly immediately clear, and it should also be clear that no other angles $\theta$ have the property that $\cos\theta=t.$

Comment: As for how I got $\cos t=0,$ note that if $0=a\cdot b$ with $a,b\in\Bbb R,$ then we have $a=0$ or $b=0.$

Comment: I got it, if you set cos(t) = 0, then it is equal to zero in the equation you wrote, if u just factor. all I needed was a simple answer, as far as what you wrote I could only get half of it, wasn't very helpful, but I see what I did wrong, thanks.

Comment: Well, are there particular parts of what I wrote that you didn't understand? I'll be happy to try to clear things up for you, if I can.